# A triangle $ABC$ is given with $BC=a,AC=b$ and $AB=\sqrt{a^2+ab}$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

A triangle $ABC$ is given with $BC=a,AC=b$ and $AB=\sqrt{a^2+ab}$. The perpendicular bisector of $AC$ intersects $AB$ at $P$. Find the perimeter of $\triangle APC$.

[image]

> Any point on the perpendicular bisector is equidistant from both the ends of the segment that they bisect.

This means that $AP=PC$, or $\triangle APC$ - isosceles. Then it is enough to find one of the legs, e.g. $AP$ in terms of the sides of $\triangle ABC$. I am not really sure I see how we can do that. If we find the ratio in which $P$ divides $AB$, it will be possible to solve for $AP$, but I don't think this is the most straightforward approach.

I don't see how to use the given side lengths and the relationship between the lengths at all. Maybe something in this direction will help us to figure out what we can do next. Thank you!

PS I've made a little mistake on the diagram. The perpendicular bisector of $AC$ should be denoted $s_{AC}$. Sorry for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the law of cosines (with $c=\sqrt{a^2+ab}$ and $\alpha=\angle CAB$),
$$a^2=b^2+c^2-2bc\cos \alpha, $$
so
$$\frac{AK}{AP}= \cos \alpha=\frac{a^2-b^2-(a^2+ab)}{-2b\sqrt{a^2+ab}}=\frac12\sqrt{1+\frac ba}.$$

Comment: Thank you! Is the answer for the perimeter of $APC$ $$\dfrac{2b\sqrt{a^2+ab}+b(a+b)}{a+b}$$ Can we further simplify?

Comment: @Medi $\dfrac{2b\sqrt{a^2+ab}+b(a+b)}{a+b}=\left(2\sqrt{\frac a{a+b}}+1\right)b$

Comment: Thank you, but I really don't see how you got that. Can you clarify it for me?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

By the [Stewart’s Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stewart%27s_theorem),

\begin{align}
|BC|^2\cdot|AP|+
|AC|^2\cdot|BP|
&=
|AB|\cdot(|CP|^2+|AP|\cdot|BP|)
,\\
a^2x+b^2(\sqrt{a^2+ab}-x)
&=
\sqrt{a^2+ab}\cdot(x^2+x(\sqrt{a^2+ab}-x))
,\\
x&=\frac{b\sqrt{a^2+ab}}{b+a}
,\\
\text{and the perimeter of }
\triangle APC
&=b\left(1+\frac{2\sqrt{a(a+b)}}{a+b}\right)
.
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for the response! Can you clarify for me how $\dfrac{2b\sqrt{a^2+ab}+b(a+b)}{a+b}$ is equal to $\left(2\sqrt{\frac a{a+b}}+1\right)b$?

Comment: @Medi:
$\dfrac{2b\sqrt{a^2+ab}+b(a+b)}{a+b}=$
$\dfrac{2b\sqrt{a(a+b)}}{\sqrt{(a+b)^2}}+b$
$=\left(2\sqrt{\frac {a(a+b)}{(a+b)^2}}+1\right)b$
$=\left(2\sqrt{\frac a{a+b}}+1\right)b$.

Answer (score 1):

Using the cosine law on $\triangle ABC$,

$$\begin{align*}
a^2 &= b^2 + (a^2+ab)-2b\sqrt{a^2+ab}\cos A\\
2b\sqrt a\sqrt{a+b}\cos A &= b(b+a)\\
\cos A &= \frac{\sqrt{a+b}}{2\sqrt a}
\end{align*}$$

Then the length of $AP=PC$ are

$$\begin{align*}
AP=PC &= \frac{AK}{\cos A}\\
&= \frac{b\sqrt a}{\sqrt{a+b}}
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Thank you for the response! Can we directly use the formula $\cos\alpha=\dfrac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}$ (standard notation)? Using it I got that $$\cos\alpha=\dfrac{a+b}{2\sqrt{a^2+ab}}$$

Comment: @Medi Yes, and in the denominator $\sqrt{a^2+ab} = \sqrt a \sqrt{a+b}$. See the answer by Hagen von Eitzen.

Comment: I saw it, but I don't understand what that minus is doing in the denominator when applying the formula for $\cos\alpha$. Anyways, should I simplify the result for $\cos\alpha$ that I got?

Comment: $AP=\dfrac{b\sqrt{a^2+ab}}{a+b}$?

Comment: @Medi Dividing both the numerator and the denominator by $\sqrt{a+b}$ is a possible simplification that many answers mention, depending on whether you prefer having a root in the denominator.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Find $\angle BAC$ using law of cosine in $\triangle ABC$.

Then $AP = \cfrac{AK}{\cos \angle BAC} \ $ in right angled triangle $\triangle AKP$.

Perimeter of $\triangle APC = 2 (AP + AK)$

Comment: Thank you! Is the answer for the perimeter of $APC$ $$\dfrac{2b\sqrt{a^2+ab}+b(a+b)}{a+b}$$ Can we further simplify?

Comment: Yes that is correct. $ \sqrt{a^2 + ab} = \sqrt a \cdot \sqrt{a+b}$ so you could alternatively write it as, $\cfrac{ b ( 2  \sqrt a + \sqrt{a+b})}{\sqrt{a+b}}$ but what you written looks better to me.